# Как обращаться к локальным функциям в своем проекте

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос такой:

У меня есть проект(папка) в котором есть следующие объекты: основной файл с кодом(.ру) и папка(в котором находятся еще файлы(.ру)).
Эти файлы(.ру) имеют функции.
Как мне грамотно обратится к этим файлам(.ру) с функциями и вызвать эти самые функции?

Пример на фотографии.

[image: 1]

Основной код Laba5.1.py, и нужно вызвать функцию, который находится в коде same_words.py.

Код файла same_word.py на всякий случай.

[image: 2]

Все было бы легче, если они находились бы в одной папке. Там можно было бы спокойно написать:

[image: 3]

Но хочется красиво и аккуратно разложить по папкам.

Много перепробовал, много гуглил, но ответа найти не могу.

В правильном ли я направлении иду? Или я вообще не так мыслю? Прошу помочь! Даже не знаю, правильно ли я вопрос задал.

Comment: Пишите `from имя_папки.имя_модуля import имя_функции`. Ну или каждую папку придется в PYTHONPATH добавлять, что не очень удобно.

Comment: дополню к комментарию, что можно добавить пути папок через сам код: `sys.path.append(...)`, в них питон будет искать при импортировании, но лучше честно делать как было указано выше :)